# How to get a subarray in numpy

Tags: numpy, sub-array

I have an 3d array and I want to get a sub-array of size (2n+1) centered around an index indx.  Using slices I can use

```
y[slice(indx[0]-n,indx[0]+n+1),slice(indx[1]-n,indx[1]+n+1),slice(indx[2]-n,indx[2]+n+1)]
```

which will only get uglier if I want a different size for each dimension.  Is there a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `slice` constructor unless you want to store the slice object for later use. Instead, you can simply do:

```
y[indx[0]-n:indx[0]+n+1, indx[1]-n:indx[1]+n+1, indx[2]-n:indx[2]+n+1]
```

If you want to do this without specifying each index separately, you can use list comprehensions:

```
y[[slice(i-n, i+n+1) for i in indx]]
```

Comment: Should be a comma not a colon y[[slice(i-n,i+n+1) for i in indx]].  Other than that thanks

Comment: @user3799584: Thanks, typo fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You can create numpy arrays for indexing into different dimensions of the `3D array` and then use use [`ix_` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) to create indexing map and thus get the sliced output. The benefit with `ix_` is that it allows for broadcasted indexing maps. More info on this could be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Then, you can specify different window sizes for each dimension for a generic solution. Here's the implementation with sample input data -

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0,9,(17,18,16))  # Input array
indx = np.array([5,10,8])              # Pivot indices for each dim
N = [4,3,2]                            # Window sizes

# Arrays of start & stop indices
start = indx - N
stop = indx + N + 1

# Create indexing arrays for each dimension
xc = np.arange(start[0],stop[0])
yc = np.arange(start[1],stop[1])
zc = np.arange(start[2],stop[2])

# Create mesh from multiple arrays for use as indexing map 
# and thus get desired sliced output
Aout = A[np.ix_(xc,yc,zc)]
```

Thus, for the given data with window sizes array, `N = [4,3,2]`, the `whos` info shows -

```
In [318]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
A          ndarray    17x18x16: 4896 elems, type `int32`, 19584 bytes
Aout       ndarray    9x7x5: 315 elems, type `int32`, 1260 bytes
```

The `whos` info for the output, `Aout` seems to be coherent with the intended output shape which must be `2N+1`.